# Get checkbox.checked value programmatically from cycling through winform controls

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox

For my winforms program, I have an Options dialog box, and when it closes, I cycle throught all the Dialog Box control names (textboxes, checkboxes, etc.) and their values and store them in a database so I can read from it in my program. As you can see below, I can easily access the `Text` property from the `Control` group, but there's no property to access the `Checked` value of the textbox. Do I need to convert `c`, in that instance, to a checkbox first?

```
conn.Open();
foreach (Control c in grp_InvOther.Controls)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_AppOptions (CONTROLNAME, VALUE) VALUES (@control, @value)";
    command = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("control",c.Name.ToString()));
    string controlVal = "";
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        controlVal = c.Text;
    else if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        controlVal = c.Checked; ***no such property exists!!***

    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("value", controlVal));
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conn.Close();
```

If I need to convert `c` first, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Yes, you do have to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to convert it:

```
else if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
    controlVal = ((CheckBox)c).Checked.ToString();
```

And you can make the check simpler to read:

```
else if (c is CheckBox)
    controlVal = ((CheckBox)c).Checked.ToString();
```

Comment: Nice answer, and thanks for the tip on shortening my code. :)

Answer (score 0):

robert's answer is good but let me give you a better one

```
TextBox currTB = c as TextBox;
if (currTB != null)
    controlVal = c.Text;
else
{
    CheckBox currCB = c as CheckBox;
    if (currCB != null)
    controlVal = currCB.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cast in place:

```
controlVal = (CheckBox)c.Checked;
```

BTW: controlVal does not need to be a string, a boolean will do the job and save memory.

Comment: This won't work you know. You are still trying to convert the Property (`Checked`) and not the Control (`c`).

Comment: Actually, `controlVal` does need to be a string because I'm also storing the `Text` property of the Textboxes.

Comment: @Mario: Wrong. 'c' is a Control object. You can cast it right in place to a CheckBox object and then directly access its properties.

Comment: @Gnarlybracket: Oh, in this case you can just add .ToString();

Comment: @Robert: Correct. That's what I did.

Comment: @Robert Yes, but `c.Checked` is evaluated before the explicit conversion `(CheckBox)`.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
controlVal = Convert.ToString(c.Checked);
```